Google Cloud functions v2 eventarc - get invoking user
I am migrating my Google Cloud functions from v1 to v2 and have found a few cases where Cloud Function gen2 has a subset of the capabilities of the previous generation - related to eventarc.
For example, in my v1 code I could get the invoking user.
exports.onMyUpdate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('/my/{myId}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
  const user = context.auth ? context.auth.uid : SYSTEM;
  const isUpdatedBySystem = user === this.SYSTEM;
  ...
  const abort = isUpdatedBySystem ? true : false;
  if (abort) {
    logger.info("Update by system - Exit");
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
  ...

But in gen2 functions eventarc does not supply this information, as far as I can see.
onValueUpdated(
  {
    region: "us-central1",
    ref: "/my/{myId}",
  },
  async (event) => {

The event only contains this data:
{
    "time": "2024-10-15T10:43:07.285Z",
    "ref": "my/1234",
    "source": "//firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/projects/_/locations/us-central1/instances/my-qa",
    "id": "1234567890=",
    "instance": "my-qa",
    "type": "google.firebase.database.ref.v1.updated",
    "subject": "refs/my/1234",
    "specversion": "1.0",
    "location": "us-central1",
    "data":
    {
        "before":
        {...},
        "after":
        {...}
    },
    "traceparent": "00-1234567890-1234567890-01",
    "firebaseDatabaseHost": "firebaseio.com",
    "params":
    {}
}

Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation regarding what to expect from event and how to handle the discrepancies between eventarc and the previous gen1 triggers.
My question is:
Do I need to rewrite my entire front end (and backend) to write the invokerId in each call to the database (add/update) or is there another way to get the invoker in v2 functions (eventarc)?

Did you check the headers? You have an authorization entry, but I fear it will be the Eventarc service account referenced in it. Maybe other useful header. I'm not a firebase user, I don't know how to test it!

Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, but when using Firebase Realtime Database triggers like onValueUpdated in Google Cloud Run Functions, the function is triggered by changes in the database rather than an HTTP request, so there are no request headers involved afaik.

Here’s an example of a trigger for the Realtime Database trigger (1st gen):
exports.onMyUpdate = functions 
.region('europe-west1') 
.database 
.ref('/my/{myId}') 
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
const user = context.auth ? context.auth.uid : SYSTEM;
const isUpdatedBySystem = user === this.SYSTEM;
...
const abort = isUpdatedBySystem ? true : false;
if (abort) {
logger.info("Update by system - Exit"); 
return Promise.resolve(true);
}
...


While for Realtime Database trigger (2nd gen). In your function source, you must import the SDK modules that you want to use.
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to setup triggers and logging.
const { onValueUpdated } = require('firebase-functions/v2/database');
const { logger } = require('firebase-functions');

exports.onMyUpdate = onValueUpdated('/my/{myId}', (event) => {
  const user = event.auth ? event.auth.uid : SYSTEM;
  const isUpdatedBySystem = user === SYSTEM;

  if (isUpdatedBySystem) {
    logger.info("Update by system - Exit");
    return;
  }
...


Note: This is just an example, modify the code as needed.

Hi @KikoZam ! Thank you, I am aware of the import requirement. I just left it out in my example. The printout for event is as described above - missing auth = auth is not present in the eventarc event object.

@Kermit, I found an answer from @Frank van Puffelen's, stating that there is no equivalent for context.auth in the 2nd generation of Cloud Functions due to the changes in the underlying architecture.
You can try this code:
async (event) =\> { 
const user = event.data.after.val();
const isUpdatedBySystem = user.updatedBy \|\| "SYSTEM";

Many thanks @KikoZam ! That clarifies things! Kind regards, K

@Kermit, I found an answer from @Frank van Puffelen's, stating that there is no equivalent for context.auth in the 2nd generation of Cloud Functions due to the changes in the underlying architecture.
You can try this code:
async (event) => { 
const user = event.data.after.data();
const isUpdatedBySystem = user.updatedBy || "SYSTEM";

